# Is it possible to restrict temporal tables moving data to history table when an update is made to specific column

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a temporal table and I don't want the data in the live table to be moved to history table when I update column1 but I need the data movement if any other column gets updated.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Any ideas would help me lot.

Thanks

Comment: how could you move that table if any field is being updated? I thought there is a table lock when updating

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to ask\